# EWS (Exchange Web Service) Getting unAuthorized Error

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am getting UnAuthorized(401) Error when trying to send, or read email

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("XXXX@YYY.COM", "XXXXXXXX");
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("XXXXXX@YYYYY.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

 EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            email.ToRecipients.Add("abc@yahoo.com");
            email.Subject = "Testing from C#";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");
            email.Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely what you are passing for the `WebCredentials`
The credentials depend on how your Exchange/Active Directory is configured.

Try passing in the format user name, password, and domain:

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
```

For more information see [WebCredentials Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.webcredentials.-ctor?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_WebCredentials__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_) and [Connecting to EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff597939(v%3Dexchg.80))